# Arduino MKRGSM 1400 giving incorrect location when connected to an MQTT

Tags: arduino, mqtt, gsm, arduino-c++

I am trying to pull location data from my mkrgsm 1400 and send it to an mqtt. For a few days now I have been struggling with inaccurate coordinates produced when running the GSM and MQTT simultaneously. I have tested my arduino using the basic MKRGSM example code 'GsmLocation' and have found that it will pull quite accurate coordinates(I am in a built up city so lots of cell towers), but as soon as I try to add a connection to MQTT the GSM will either give a default coordinate of 54, -2 (Which is no where near me at all) or a coordinate that is on the other side of the city. I do not understand why implementing an MQTT throws the coordinates off.

EDIT: I have been doing a lot of experimenting to rule out any possibilities that could be causing this issue. I have tried it with both the MQTT library and the PubSubClient library, both give the same thrown off coordinates. I think that my problem may be that when I try to publish to the mqtt (This can be any message - not location specific) it seems to throw the coordinates off, I'm not sure if maybe the mqtt connection and the location connection are somewhat fighting each other? Maybe there is a different way to lay out the code that will stop this?

Here is my code:

```
#include <MKRGSM.h>
#include <MQTT.h>
#include <avr/dtostrf.h>

const char pin[]      = "";
const char apn[]      = "";
const char login[]    = "";
const char password[] = "";

GSMLocation location;
GSMClient net;
GPRS gprs;
GSM gsmAccess;
MQTTClient client;
char pubCharsPayload[100];

void connect() {
  // connection state
  bool connected = false;

  Serial.print("connecting to cellular network ...");
  while (!connected) {
    if ((gsmAccess.begin(pin) == GSM_READY) &&
        (gprs.attachGPRS(apn, login, password) == GPRS_READY)) {
      connected = true;
      Serial.println("Connected to cellular network!");
    } else {
      Serial.print(".");
      delay(1000);
    }
  }

  Serial.print("Connecting to MQTT...");
  while (!client.connect("","","")) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(1000);
  }

  Serial.println("Connected to MQTT!");

  client.subscribe("/location");
}

void messageReceived(String &topic, String &payload) {
  Serial.println("incoming: " + topic + " - " + payload);
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  client.begin("broker.shiftr.io", net);
  client.onMessage(messageReceived);

  connect();
  location.begin();
}

void loop() {
  client.loop();

  if (!client.connected()) {
    connect();
  }

if (location.available()){
    //Construct the string for the latitude
    char bufferLat[20];
    //Uses dtostrf library to convert
    String latVal = dtostrf(location.latitude(), 10, 7, bufferLat);
    //Construct the string for the longitude
    char bufferLon[20];
    String lonVal = dtostrf(location.longitude(), 10, 7, bufferLon);
      char bufferAcc[20];
    String accVal = dtostrf(location.accuracy(), 10, 7, bufferAcc);

    //Construct the payload as a JSON object
    String payload = "{\"Latitude\":" + latVal + ",\"Longitude\":" + lonVal + ",\"Accuracy\":" + accVal + "}";
//        String payload = "{\"Latitude\":" + latVal + ",\"Longitude\":" + lonVal + "}";
    payload.toCharArray(pubCharsPayload, (payload.length() + 1));
    //Pushes data to MQTT every 12000 milliseconds
    delay(5000);
    client.publish("/location", pubCharsPayload);
}
}
`
```

Comment: can you please explain where do you call the`loop()` function? it's quite hard to determine *when* the `location.available()` execution takes place in your flow...

Comment: @ymz I have not called upon it directly within my code, do I need to? It seems to run after the void setup() as it doesn't start sending the location until after "Connected to MQTT" is printed

Comment: I understand that the `location` logic (from within `loop` function) **finished after** the `setup` function.. but I do want that this code **also** executed **after** the `setup` function (and not before that) to ensure that there is no sync problem between MQTT and location components

Comment: @ymz `setup()` and `loop()` are two Arduino interfaces that the user have to fll with their code. The first i called once at startup, the second is called in an infinite loop after setup.